# python 2.7 cpickle.load adds \r to strings in dictionaries

Tags: python, pickle

I am saving a dictionary with keys that are strings and values that are tuples of numbers with pickle.dump
the format is f the type:
{u'abc': (1,2,3), u'efg': (4,5,6)}

when I load this dictionary with pickle.load \r is added to the keys:
{u'abc\r': (1,2,3), u'efg\r': (4,5,6)}

I am working on Centos. On some Centos machines it does not reconstruct and the dictionary is loaded normally.
Does anyone has a clue to the reason for that?

Comment: Please reduce your original program to the smallest possible **complete**, **runnable** program that demonstrates the error. (I suppose that might be 10 lines or so in your case.) Please copy-paste that **entire** short program into your question. For more information about asking questions that produce excellent answers, see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: This seems like something that could be caused by some machines using `\n` for new lines and others using `\r\n`.

Comment: I agree with @JaredGoguen.